# Fatal error: Call to undefined method: domdocument->load()

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have this weird issue with a page that has been working for 10 years, up until now.

Here is my code :

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$QuelXml = "DATA/mydata.xml";   
$dom->load($QuelXml);
```

I get a

```
Fatal error: Warning: domdocument() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in php/loadXml.php on line 9

Fatal error: Call to undefined method: domdocument->load() in php/loadXml.php on line 13
```

I don't see anywhere that it's not supported by a new php version.
What should I do ?

thanks,

Comment: Can you post your full and exact error message?

Comment: If you use `new DomDocument();` under namespace, rewrite this to `new \DomDocument();` instead.

Comment: @vee I then get : Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in php/loadXml.php on line 9

Comment: @aynber, I updated my question to include the full error message.

Comment: Um... What PHP version do you using? If it is 5.3 or newer it is not possible to error with ``\`` character. From your latest update about error message, I think you are using PHP very very old version.

Comment: According to [this comment on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php#86225), it may be due to an old domxml extension that needs to be disabled.